# fgets maximum size read

Tags: c, string, fgets

Using `fgets` to input a string, I have doubts related to length of string read.

For example, consider the following program.

```
char str[50];
int i;
int len;
printf("Enter name:\n");
fgets(str,11,stdin);
len = strlen(str);
printf("len :  %d\n",len);
```

1. If I enter `123456789`, `strlen` gives 10.
2. If I enter `1234567890`, `strlen` given is 10 again ??

I think `strlen` is considering newline also for string length. Am I correct?
(I understand `fgets` using newline as part of string)

What's wrong with (2) where I enter exactly 10 characters, Here string length should be 11 right? 10 + 1 (for newline) = 11

Comment: printf("len : %d",len); printf("str : %s",str); printf("hi");return 0; } Adding few prints helps to clarify the answers given below. Notice how "hi" is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` reads at most 1 fewer characters than the length argument given, and **does** retain the newline as part of the input - so long as the newline is part of the first (length - 1) characters.

So in your first case, assuming that `123456789` is followed by a newline, `fgets` has read 9 characters including the newline, yielding a string length of 10; in your second case, `fgets` will stop after reading the 10 characters `1234567890`, yielding a string length of 10.

Comment: Minor correction: it will *not* retain the newline if #/characters >= max length.  As illustrated in the example below.

Comment: @paulsm4 I believe that's already clear from my first line: _reads at most 1 fewer characters than the length argument given_.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 5

int
main ()
{
  char buf[80];
  char *s = NULL;
  printf ("\n>>Enter string, %d digits or less: ", MAX_DIGITS);
  s = fgets (buf, MAX_DIGITS+1, stdin);
  printf ("strlen(buf)=%d, buf=%s, strlen(s)=%d, s=%s\n",
    strlen(buf), buf, strlen(s), s);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output, with "MAX_DIGITS" and "MAX_DIGITS + 1":

```
>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 1
strlen(buf)=2, buf=1
, strlen(s)=2, s=1
.

>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 12
strlen(buf)=3, buf=12
, strlen(s)=3, s=12
.

>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 123
strlen(buf)=4, buf=123
, strlen(s)=4, s=123
.

>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 1234
strlen(buf)=5, buf=1234
, strlen(s)=5, s=1234
.

>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 12345
strlen(buf)=5, buf=12345, strlen(s)=5, s=12345.

>>Enter string, 5 digits or less: 123456
strlen(buf)=5, buf=12345, strlen(s)=5, s=12345.
```

You'll notice:

1. The return buffer retains the "\n" as long as the #/digits are < MAX_DIGITS.
2. The "\n" is REMOVED when #/digits >= MAX_DIGITS.
3. Your buffer must accomodate MAX_DIGITS+1

Comment: <<Your buffer must accomodate MAX_DIGITS+1.                                                  So buffer should have enough space to store newline too, which is +1.    Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kumar To store newline is should be + 2 as fgets is already taking away one for storing a null terminator value -> '\0'; That is, if you pass it 6 it will read at most 5 things (4 digits + CR or 5 digits). If you pass it 7 it will read 5 digits plus a carriage return.

Answer (score -1):

Actually `fgets` requires a `size` specification (in your case `11`) account for the `\0` at the end of a string. From the `fgets` man page:

> **fgets()**  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters
>          from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to  by
>          s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline
>          is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null
>          byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So we know that reading stops at `\n`, when you enter `123456789\n`. However when you enter `1234567890\n`, `fgets()` processes the input but it only takes the 10 characters and ignores everything else afterwards.

Any extra input of your string and your string will at `size-1` of `fget()` with last character as `\0` so the output remains the same.